# how to change the pagenumbering position in scrbook?

Tags: header-footer, scrpage2

I am writing a document in lyx using scrbook
I want to change the numbers in every page from bottom to top
With the folowing code in the preamble I get it,but I think the default position remains so now I have two page numbers in every page

```
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\oldstylenums}
\rehead[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\lohead[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
```

I am not sure I understand this
Can anybody help please
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with `scrbook`, so I retagged it. Actually `scrpage2` is independent of the KOMA-Script classes, it can be used together with other classes as well (`\addtokomafont` would not work, then).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First you have to clear all footers say by iissuing

```
\clearscrheadfoot
```

as in

```
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\oldstylenums}

\clearscrheadfoot %% <-----
\rehead[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\lohead[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
```

Reference: scrguien.pdf chapter 4 and page 113.

Comment: Thanks a lot  Uhmm how can I say this question is answered?

Comment: @murpholinox: You can do so by  accepting the answer by clicking the green tick mark on left below the voting symbols. You may also consider upvoting if the answer  is  useful to you.